# How to define function with different templates as input

Tags: c++

I am completely new to C++ (and Stack Overflow), so please bear with me. I am trying to create two templates and a function that takes inputs from both templates.

I have tried to make some sample code that resembles my code, and which reproduces the error. Basically I have two templates Dog and Cat, and want to create an operator function which takes an instance of Dog and Cat respectively, but I am really struggling with how to write the function header. After having spent a lot of time reading Stack Overflow posts, I have thrown in keywords 'template' and 'typename' in an attempt to make it work, but I keep getting errors. Currently the error is

> candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'

```
template <class T> class Dog
{
private:
    int size;

public:
  Dog(int size1)
    {
        size = size1;
    }
};

template <class T> class Cat
{
private:
    int size;

public:
    Cat(int size1)
    {
        size = size1;
    }

};

template <class T> // What to write here?
typename Cat<T>::template Cat<T> operator*(typename Dog<T>::template Dog<T> m,typename Cat<T>::template Cat<T> v)
{
    Cat<int> return_cat(1);
    return return_cat;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{

    Cat<double>::Cat<double> new_cat(2);

    Dog<double>::Dog<double> new_dog(4);

    Cat<double>::Cat<double> result = new_dog*new_cat; // ERROR couldn't infer template argument 'T'

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: How should I define the function header for the `operator*` function to avoid any errors?

Comment: Why do you write all types twice?

Comment: You have a lot of syntax issues with this code. Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to help you with the syntax for classes and templates.

Comment: @JVApen Haha, I didn't know what I was doing. :)

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you, some good suggestions there! Will definitely check some of them out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you were trying to do with all the scope operators. You don't need them. Simply use the proper types. I have added const references because it looked reasonable for this scenario. They are not strictly required.

```
template <class T>
Cat<T> operator*(const Dog<T>& m, const Cat<T>& v)
{
    Cat<T> return_cat(1);
    return return_cat;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    Cat<double> new_cat(2);    
    Dog<double> new_dog(4);    
    Cat<double> result = new_dog * new_cat;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: while this looks much nicer it still gives me the same error

Comment: @Thomas Well, let's put it this way, what error are you getting? That might help us answer.

Comment: @NicoSchertler same as the OP, see [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a08709fdc6faa2e)

Comment: @Thomas Yours also compiles. You only get a warning that `result` is unused. The error message that you see is from the comment and not an actual error message.

Comment: @NicoSchertler never mind, i'm just blind. it's an unused variable warning with the comment displaying the unused variable text ... (shame)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your intended use of `operator*()` is, but generally it will look something like this:

```
template <class T> 
Cat<T> operator*(Dog<T> m, Cat<T> v)
```

This allows a cat and dog to be multiplied if their template class is the same.

If they are not the same (that is, cat and dog have different types), you will want something like this instead:

```
template <class T1, class T2> 
Cat<T2> operator*(Dog<T1> m, Cat<T2> v)
```

This allows for cat and dog to have different types and be multiplied together.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the different types, I wasn't aware! Would upvote, but can't yet

Comment: Prefer `Cat<decltype(std::declval<T1>()+std::declval<T2>()))>` for the return type in the second case, so a short cat multiplied by a long dog is a long cat?

Comment: @Bathsheba Didn't know that was a thing. Really awesome.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify it a little bit for easier "reading" and not "mixing" dogs with cats :), you can play with this overload

```
template <class T>
class Animal
{
  private:
    T size;
  public:
  Animal(T size1) {
    size = size1;
  }
  T getSize() {
     return size;
}
Animal<T> operator*(Animal<T> animal1)
{
  T a = animal1.getSize();
  T b = this->getSize();
  Animal<T> animal = Animal<T>(a*b);
  return animal;
 }
```

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {

```
Animal<double> cat(2);
Animal<double> dog(4);
Animal<double> result( dog*cat );
return 0;
```

}